# Counting how many seconds a user dragging the mouse

Tags: javascript

I have a function where the user sort of "scratching" a surface when he drags the mouse over it, reviling content underneath this surface. I want to count how many seconds he dragged the mouse, and when he reaches 5 seconds - do something. If he lets go after, for example, 3 seconds, the count should stop and resume from 3d second when he resumes dragging. I tried to do it with `setInterval` and add 1 to seconds counter every 1000 ms, but no matter what I've tried - I'm either getting some crazy numbers in the counter or it just stays on 0. Here's my code:

```
var interval, info;
var totalSeconds = 0;

function init()
{
    ...more vars declaration and initialization

function scratchOff(x, y)
{
    mainctx.save();
    mainctx.beginPath();
    mainctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    mainctx.clip();
    mainctx.drawImage(bottomImage, 0, 0);
    mainctx.restore();
}

$('#overlay').mousedown(function(e){
        isMouseDown = true;
        var relX = e.pageX;
        var relY = e.pageY;
        scratchOff(relX, relY, true);
});

$('#overlay').mousemove(function(e){
    var relX = e.pageX;
    var relY = e.pageY;
    overlayctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, relX-radius, relY-radius);
    if (isMouseDown) {
        scratchOff(relX, relY, false);
        countSeconds(); // - THIS CALLS FOR THE FUNCTION THAT IS SUPPOSED 
                        // TO COUNT SECONDS ONCE THE USER STARTS DRAGGING THE MOUSE
    }

});
$('#overlay').mouseup(function(e){
    isMouseDown = false;
    clearInterval(interval);
});

var mainctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var radius = 10;
topImage.onload = function(){
    mainctx.drawImage(topImage, 0, 0);
};
topImage.src = "images/oie_canvas.png"; 
}

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT'S SUPPOSED TO COUNT SECONDS
function countSeconds() {
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        totalSeconds = totalSeconds++;
        info.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
        if(totalSeconds >= 5) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1000);
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: possible for you to create a jsfiddle.net of this please? Also are you saying you only want to start the timer once a person has started moving the mouse? or everytime the mousemove event is triggered? (ie. mousedown triggered, move 1px, stops moving.. does the timer still count? or only WHILE the person is moving?)

Comment: @haxxxton Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jore6jgn/ And I want the seconds to be counted only if the user is actually dragging the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would start a timer of 1 sec, which monitor your isMouseDown flag and start counting, when you reach 5 sec you go for your action, no need to call the countSeconds every time.

Here is an example:

**EDITED**

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    if(isMouseDown) { 
        totalSeconds++;
    }
    if(totalSeconds== 5) {
        //do your action;
        totalSeconds = 0;
    }
    info.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}, 1000);
} );

var isMouseDown = false;

function init()
{

... your code
}
```

**EDITED 2**

Full Example

```
var topImage = new Image();
var bottomImage = new Image();
var coinImage = new Image();
bottomImage.src = "http://i58.tinypic.com/2i093ia.jpg";
coinImage.src = "http://i61.tinypic.com/30acmtt.png";   
var info;
var interval;
var totalSeconds = 0;

$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    if(isMouseDown) { 
        totalSeconds++;
    }
    if(totalSeconds== 5) {
        alert("5 sec");
        totalSeconds = 0;
    }
    info.innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}, 1000);
} );

var isMouseDown = false;

function init()
{

    var canvasWidth = $('#myCanvas').width();
    var canvasHeight = $('#myCanvas').height();
    $('body').append('<canvas id="overlay" width="'+canvasWidth+'" height="'+canvasHeight+'" />');
    var overlayctx = $('canvas')[1].getContext('2d');
    overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, 0,0);
    info = document.getElementById('info');

    function scratchOff(x, y)
    {
        mainctx.save();
        mainctx.beginPath();
        mainctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        mainctx.clip();
        mainctx.drawImage(bottomImage, 0, 0);
        mainctx.restore();
    }

    $('#overlay').mousedown(function(e){
            isMouseDown = true;
            var relX = e.pageX;
            var relY = e.pageY;
            scratchOff(relX, relY, true);
    });
    $('#overlay').mousemove(function(e){
        var relX = e.pageX;
        var relY = e.pageY;
        overlayctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
        overlayctx.drawImage(coinImage, relX-radius, relY-radius);
        if (isMouseDown) {
            scratchOff(relX, relY, false);
            countSeconds();
        }

    });
    $('#overlay').mouseup(function(e){
        isMouseDown = false;
        clearInterval(interval);
    });

    var mainctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var radius = 10;
    topImage.onload = function(){
        mainctx.drawImage(topImage, 0, 0);
    };
    topImage.src = "http://i61.tinypic.com/xpzbx0.png"; 
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not implementing it right, but I tried it both in my .mousemove callback function and in my countSeconds function and in both cases I'm keep getting some huge numbers, starting with 0 and reaching hundreds in a matter of a few seconds. Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/jore6jgn/1/

Comment: @Shadi The problem essentially remains the same: when will you call that `setInterval` code? You would have to do it in the `mousemove` and will end up creating multiple intervals again.

Comment: Please move the setInterval outside the init function, make it called from the ready function, and move the isMouseDown to be global variable. I have edited the answer.

Comment: OK, that's getting closer! Any idea how to do it without using jQuery, only with pure JS? I know I have jQ right now, but eventually I'll have to get rid of it and select and create elements by using JS only.

Comment: OK, never mind, I just moved your `setInterval` inside my `init()` function, which is being called once the body is loaded, and it worked great! Thank you so very much! :)